# Php-MySql Security approach while INSERT’ing INTO MySql & fetching from MySql to screen

Tags: php, mysql, security, prepared-statement, parameterized

### My Approach while INSERT’ing INTO MySql

I think I read in stackoverflow.com that “if you need escaping or similar action, do it just in time you need” so in the verification pages that I verify the user inputs (null or not check, length check and structural checks (eg: mail structure, custom tags structures); I use the `$_POST['']` variables as inputs. During verifications, even in the custom error printing parts, my error messages does not include any of `$_POST['']` values in message texts.
As an interim note: I utilize **prepared statements and parameterized queries** during php-MySql interactions. If inputs are verified; just before INSERT’ing INTO MySql, I **strip the tags from input** since I don’t allow any html tags other than custom structured tags. (for example `**bold text** === <strong>bold text</strong>`) Then I insert the user input into MySql db.

### My Approach while fetching from MySql & printing the output to the screen

I only apply htmlspecialchars() command to print out to the screen from MySql db

### My Question

I am not sure of myself. Is there any obvious or hidden weakness in my approach? Thanks in advance for php gurus’ valuable comments. BR

## UPDATE

I won't strip tags during insert into MySql db. For reasons, Please refer to comments of ÁlvaroG.Vicario below. BR.

Comment: If your input is not HTML, don't strip HTML tags. You're just corrupting user data.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario what if user inputs some javascript or smilar malicious code? Then I will accept these inputs into mysql db. But since I will use htmlspecialchars during printing onto screen, malicious code can not be dangerous. So stripping tags has no benefit. Did I understand correct? And can you give 1 example that I would need stripping tags during INSERT INTO please? thanks, BR

Comment: It'd be harmless if it just didn't have benefits. What I mean is that you can actually *break* what the user cared typing. Please don't do it.

Comment: ok, thank you, I will update my question wrt your comments. BR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion thus far has been about protecting from SQL Injection and Persistent cross site scripting.  It sounds like you're on the right track.

- Your use of prepared statements is a "best practice" to combat SQL injection.
- htmlspecialchars() is a good start to prevent XSS, but you have to escape data in the encoding scheme that is appropriate to where you are outputting data.  OWASP has a comprehensive page that discusses this: [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).  The short answer:  Ensure you are using "`the escape syntax for the part of the HTML document you're putting untrusted data into.`"

Answer (score 0):

## I tried code below in trial.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="tr"> 
<head> 
<title>trial</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="tr" /> 
<meta name="Description" content="trial page." /> 
<meta name="Robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
$str1 = '<script>alert(\'inside of input with quote\')</script>';
$str2 = '<script>alert("inside of input with quote")</script>';
$str3 = "<script>alert(\"inside of input with quote\")</script>";
$str4 = '<script>alert("outside of form")</script>';
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>alert attempts inside form inputs</legend>
        <label for="input1">label 1:</label><br />
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($str1) ; ?>" name="input1" id="input1" /><br /><br />

        <legend>attempt 2</legend>
        <label for="input2">label 2:</label><br />
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($str2) ; ?>" name="input2" id="input2" /><br /><br />

        <label for="input3">Label 3:</label><br />
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($str3) ; ?>" name="input3" id="input3" />
    </fieldset>
</form>    
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($str4) ; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

## results of trial.php

1. what the user cared typing didn't break, so user data did not
   corrupted
2. I see exactly what the user cared typing on screen
3. script alerts did not work

## resulted procedure while INSERT’ing INTO MySQL & fetching from MySQL and printing the output to screen

1. utilize prepared statements and parametric queries during
   php-MySQL interactions. while INSERT’ing INTO MySQl db, this approach prevents  SQL Injections already so no need to extra escaping. Extra effort like `strip_tags()` will disrupt what the user exactly cared typing just like `htmlspecialchars()` OR `htmlentities()` will do also.
2. utilize prepared statements and parametric queries also while
   fetching from MySQL db
3. while printing user inputted data onto screen, use
   `htmlspecialchars()` so what the user exactly cared typing won't
   break and possible malicious special characters will be converted to
   their corresponding HTML entities