# Empty fields after POST with HTML / PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

For learning purposes I'm trying to **insert data from HTML form to a MySQL database**, this is the code I've got for the form:

```
<form action="newmovie.php" method="post">

            <p>Titulo:  <input type="text" name="movieTitle"> </p>
            <p>Año:  <input type="text" name="movieYear"> </p>
            <p>Director:  <input type="text" name="movieDirector"> </p>
            <p>Protagonista:  <input type="text" name =movieProtagonist> </p>
            <input type="submit"  class="button" value="Agregar">

</form>
```

So, in same *webpage* I check if a POST is being performed:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        include("connectDB.php");
        $mySQL=new MySQL();

        $movieTitle=$_GET['movieTitle']; 
        $movieDirector=$_GET['movieDirector'];    
        $movieYear=$_GET['movieYear'];    
        $movieProtagonist=$_GET['movieProtagonist'];
        echo "INSERT INTO peliculas (titulo,director,year, protagonista) VALUES ('$movieTitle','$movieDirector','$movieYear', '$movieProtagonist')";
        $queryResult=$mySQL->query("INSERT INTO peliculas (titulo,director,year, protagonista) VALUES ('$movieTitle','$movieDirector','$movieYear', '$movieProtagonist')");
        echo "$queryResult";    
    }
?>
```

So, inserting is done BUT the fields are empty, this is what the echo prints:

> INSERT INTO peliculas (titulo,director,year, protagonista) VALUES ('','','', '')

What's that I'm doing wrong with my code?

Comment: in php file use $_POST instead of $_GET, and check $_POST['submit'] == 'Agregar' in if condition. and do a mysql_real_escape_string for better coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="newmovie.php" method="post">
```

Since your form method is post, you need to use

```
$movieTitle=$_POST['movieTitle'];
```

You could alternatively use

```
$movieTitle=$_REQUEST['movieTitle'];
```

for both post and get but this would cause unneccessary overhead

Comment: How do you mean about the overhead?

Answer (score 2):

Fix the typo here

```
<p>Protagonista:  <input type="text" name =movieProtagonist> </p>
```

by changing it to

```
<p>Protagonista:  <input type="text" name="movieProtagonist"> </p>
```

Change the PHP to:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        include("connectDB.php");
        $mySQL=new MySQL();

        $movieTitle=$_POST['movieTitle']; 
        $movieDirector=$_POST['movieDirector'];    
        $movieYear=$_POST['movieYear'];    
        $movieProtagonist=$_POST['movieProtagonist'];
        echo "INSERT INTO peliculas (titulo,director,year, protagonista) VALUES ('$movieTitle','$movieDirector','$movieYear', '$movieProtagonist')";
        $queryResult=$mySQL->query("INSERT INTO peliculas (titulo,director,year, protagonista) VALUES ('$movieTitle','$movieDirector','$movieYear', '$movieProtagonist')");
        echo "$queryResult";    
    }
?>
```

Explanation:

You can submit a form to a PHP script by using HTTP GET or HTTP POST. You define this in the form. In your form, you set it to send it via POST but were trying to retrieve it in php using $_GET.

Get is good for if you need to send URLS and should only be used for retrieving data from the database. Get variables are passed like this

http://yourserver.com/yourscript.php?variable1=something&variable2=somethingElse

And post is hidden in the HTTP request (you don't see it in the URL). It's better to use 'post' for any request that is making changes to the DB.

You can read more about the differences here:
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post

Comment: One more question, I know it's kinda off scope of the question, though:

If I get any string with accents or such characters like ñ, How can I catch them properly to be stored in database.

Comment: Good question, not a simple of single answer unfortunately. You need to make sure any script you use to access/change the database is secure and prevents things like "Injection" attacks. There are lots of other posts that cover this on SO, such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741557/php-mysql-security-approach-while-inserting-into-mysql-fetching-from-mysql-to. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP file instead of the

```
$_GET
```

use the

```
$_REQUEST
```

And your problem will solve as you are using the `method='post'` in the form tag.
And you are getting the data by `$_GET` which is used to get the data of method get.

> Always use the `$_REQUEST` to get the data from form as it is common
>   to get the both data from get and post.

Comment: Yeah! I got it right. Seems such an stupid question now. When would I use _GET, _PUT or _DELETE?

Comment: @Diego there is only `$_GET` , `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST` to get the data. so such _PUT, and _DELETE global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use $_POST to read form data:
example: `$movieTitle=$_POST['movieTitle'];`

Answer (score 1):

try the code below, it will fix your issue.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $movieTitle=$_POST['movieTitle']; 
    $movieDirector=$_POST['movieDirector'];    
    $movieYear=$_POST['movieYear'];    
    $movieProtagonist=$_POST['movieProtagonist'];
    echo "INSERT INTO peliculas (titulo,director,year, protagonista) VALUES ('".$movieTitle."','".$movieDirector."','".$movieYear."', '".$movieProtagonist."')";
    $queryResult=$mySQL->query("INSERT INTO peliculas (titulo,director,year, protagonista) VALUES ('".$movieTitle."','".$movieDirector."','".$movieYear."', '".$movieProtagonist."')");
    echo "$queryResult";    
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Since method='post'

```
Instead of $_GET['']
```

use either

```
$_POST['']
```

or

```
$_REQUEST['']
```